# Azure AD role not showing in Auth or ID token for guest user

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, postman

I feel like this question has been asked several times before but I'm not getting clued in or finding out what I need to know.

I have an Azure AD with two tenants.  Tenant 1 has all our users in it.  Tenant 2 is meant for external users making inbound api calls - we are in the proof of concept stage right now.

All works great when I set up new users in tenant 2.  The users are created, the app is created, the scopes for the api are defined and finally using the enterprise app, roles are created with local users assigned to the roles.  The .Net Core app is decorated with [Authenticate Roles("Read, Write"], etc.  The scopes are then validated using the HttpContext.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(scopeRequiredByApi); inside each controller method.  As I said, it all works great with users who have been defined as local users in Tenant 2.

If it helps, we are using Postman to test with.

However, if I modify the login call to simply use the guest user, which an existing user in the Azure AD client 1 tenant I see the following behavior.  The user is Authenticate and a user_token as well as an id_token is returned.  Calling the existing PUT and POST API methods always returns a 403 Forbidden.  I had read that a guest id should use the auth_token so that is what I have done but to no avail.

If anyone has any advice on where I should look, if I am overlooking something simple or if there is a config value I'm not making I'd love to hear it.  I realize I'm low on actual code snippets but there really aren't any.  The API works just fine and the Postman call work great for local users.  It's simply the guest users that aren't getting assigned to a "proper" role.

EDIT - the appsettings.json file relevant bits:

```json
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Domain": "tenant01.onmicrosoft.com", // the domain for tenant 1
    "TenantId": "common"
  },
```

And the startup.cs file:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);
   services.AddControllers();

   // some other code...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
       endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]

The auth token for the guest user does show the scope but the role is missing.  The id token for the guest user simply shows the standard user claims - Name, preferred_username, the issuing tenant, etc.

I'm missing something that's probably not terribly difficult to set up but I've no idea what to do from here.

Comment: Which api are you calling?

Comment: I am calling a custom API call pocDemoApiAd shown in the above screenshot.  It is a simple REST API with GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured this out.  No changes were made to the code or the json file.  The URL used to call the authentication was modified.  The URL that was changed from:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
**TO this url**
https://login.microsoftonline.com/< tenantid >/oauth2/v2.0/token

This change caused the role to appear in the id_token.  I had read that the id_token needed to be used but I was not aware of the change that needed to be made to the url to include the tenant id.